# Using MVVM Light and Okra Framework Together

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, mvvm-light, okra-framework

I am new to Win 8 Development (Just started planning an app) and know people using MVVM light for Windows Phone.

My Oneline Surfing for Development Framework I selected 2 Frameworks:

1. [MVVM Light for Win 8](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com)
2. [Okra Framework for Win RT](http://okra.codeplex.com/)

And after reading the blogs I am pretty confused on what to use.

What are the advantages these will provide over one another and also .. Can I use Both of them in a single project (I Prefer MEF way of using Containers but like the VS Templates of MVVM lights)

Any Help in this direction would be helpful....

Comment: Hello @adcool20007. Since you have asked this 4 months ago can you please tell me what has been your experience with those frameworks? Maybe you could answer your own question to help others like me that are now thinking of using those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

After using both frameworks... I share here my experience....

If I want simple DI, MVVM Light is the way to go....

But I always like MEF and hence I used OKRA F/W.

Also the are lot of useful classes for the different features of Win 8 Apps (Navigation, Settings pane) etc....

And yes it's easy to use as tutorial are always available... and the author response were prompt...